# The question about MS Graph API "Create Group"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When I call the MS Graph API (create a group) , with 21 users(1 owner + 20 members). It failed with the following error:

> "A resource cannot contain more than 20 link changes".

When I call the MS Graph API (create a group) , with 20 users(1 owner + 19 members), it succeeds.

I want to know the reason to explain above phenomenon.

Whether it relates to as each member will result in an Add to group action, which could be considered a batch (i.e. 20 add to group actions).

Limit on batch size JSON batch requests are currently limited to 20 individual requests.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues

Please clarify.

Repro steps:

Call "Create Group" API
pass 1 owner and 20 members to get this error:  "A resource cannot contain more than 20 link changes".

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
{

    "description": "Test Create o365 Group ACN Admin 2-1",
    "displayName": "Test Create o365 Group ACN Admin 03 Sep 2019 2-1",
    "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
    ],
    "mailEnabled": true,
    "visibility": "Private",
    "mailNickname": "TestCreateo365GroupACNAdmin2-1",
    "securityEnabled": false,
    "owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/d8315eb0-7353-4958-870a-0ffb0f7f0294"
    ],
    "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/16bdaa60-704d-434f-8fe5-acae7dc2592e",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/33c7be88-32c2-40f4-99a5-69df118da872",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/babc66a9-af90-43ac-bc75-969bbe114c32",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/36d35ddd-08a8-4f5a-987b-b7df94c7ec4e",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/398a4e5e-efe7-4af0-a478-828678d823b4",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/b7842e71-49e7-4556-9549-189a1b87ec29",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/7314d516-555a-4d1f-b4e8-7125d5fbd261",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ac516c9e-3a34-4a96-9436-a089d932ebf5",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/7f725fff-f09b-4a67-befd-0d580a8ee492",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/82db9df1-4b96-4ac7-aa51-003372beb28b",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/0834b356-ae4a-4d48-a4da-05f63cb856ae",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/0d7e8c36-a21a-436b-9883-5b3278aa6080",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/a2f5ad0b-045a-47d5-915f-d2b38163936c",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/1f8fa935-7f75-4608-aafa-04c62fc6db53",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/fa13ba80-2b33-45bd-bf8a-9c488d8d1daa",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/79d64a31-8600-41a9-8d5e-b183a1507e98",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/8e7dd352-1c1e-4a23-8668-ff580a4524f9",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/acd6da7d-dfdf-4284-aa15-31eeaea89289",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/5b976ca1-7eae-408b-b462-745a5288d4f2",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ce499f5a-22fa-462f-9b9c-9a7b3f848af2",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/5df4c1d7-dadc-4a53-8435-7bab4a131535",
    ]

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be a limit of `members@odata.bind`, not relate to [`Limit on batch size`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#limit-on-batch-size),  batch request sample format [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching#first-json-batch-request).

When I test the batch limit, the error will be `Number of requests inside batch exceed the limit`.

[image]

If you want to add more than 20 members to the group, you could try this api [`Add member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) after creating the group.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark button on the left of the reply to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Comment: Thanks Joy. I know the workaround. Currently just want to know real reason for this error "A resource cannot contain more than 20 link changes". Or state this clearly in the MSDN document.

Comment: @RiquelDong Well, never find the doc mentions that, if so, you can [send a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and update the result here.